# How not to overflow on the left when using justify-content: space-evenly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

In a grid layout with `justify-content: space-evenly`, when the columns are jointly wider than the container, the content is centered and overflows both left and right. I'd expect it to align left and only overflow on the right (like is the case with `space-between`).

`space-evenly`: https://jsfiddle.net/78yv9uhp/5/

[image: Space evenly overflows its container left and right.]

`space-between`: https://jsfiddle.net/78yv9uhp/6/

[image]

This is particularly noticeable when adding scrollbars (like `overflow: auto`) to the container. The content on the right can be scrolled to, but the left-overflowing content remains unreachable.

Is this intended behaviour? And is there a way to get the content to align left when it overflows?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `justify-content: space-evenly`?

Comment: Yes, for aesthetics. The content is dynamic (and viewports vary in width). Many times the content fits just fine and I like to space the columns evenly. Sometimes there is too much content, or the visitor has a small window. Then I don't want content to be hidden from them.

Comment: Can you not re-define grid template for smaller screens?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can achieve it through `justify-content: left`

An example:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: .75em solid;
  padding: .75em;
  width: 220px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 170px 70px;
  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  grid-gap: 10px;

  justify-content: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
.cell {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
  border: 3px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

In addition, you can remove `justify-content` property. Thanks to [@doğukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10698741/do%C4%9Fukan) and [@Mr t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12667595/mr-t)

An example:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: .75em solid;
  padding: .75em;
  width: 220px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 170px 70px;
  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  grid-gap: 10px;

  justify-content: left;
}
.cell {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
  border: 3px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If space between columns should be the same when `overflow: auto`, then we can set the same values for `padding` and `grid-gap`.

An example:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: .75em solid;
  padding: .75em;
  width: 220px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 170px 70px;
  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  grid-gap: .75em;

  justify-content: space-evenly;
  overflow: auto;
}
.cell {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
  border: 3px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you remove the `justify-content` you will get the same result

Comment: @doğukan yeah, you are right. I've updated my reply. Thanks!

Comment: I might as well use `space-between`, right?

Comment: @Paul yeah. You can use `space-between`. I cannot reproduce bug that your described in question.

Comment: @Paul I just updated my answer. Maybe it will help you, if I understood you correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found the [CSS specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#distribution-values) describe a "fallback alignment" in case the spacing cannot be applied. For `space-between` this is `start` whereas for `space-evenly` this is `center`, unfortunately. This explains the observed overlap difference.

Nevertheless, the spec also mentions

> A future level of this module may allow the fallback alignment to be specified explicitly.

so perhaps with time we may be able to set the fallback to `start`.

Until that time I've found a workaround: set `min-width` on the container. To avoid excessive width, wrap the container in a scrolling parent element. [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/oL7yke6g/).